# Trying to set a field using Jquery - does not work

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to to get this to work. I'm using JQuery and kind of new to this.
The alert message is ---> before...function(a){return J......
and the script does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() 
        {                
            $("input").click(function()
            {

                alert('before...' + $(this).text);

                if ($(this).text == "Search  ")
                {
                   $(this).val("You have set me to value.");   
                   $(this).css({"style.color":"#000000"});
                   $(this).css({"fontStyle":"italic"});  
                }
                else
                {
                   $(this).val("");                      
                }

                alert('after...' + $(this).text);                    

           });          
        });

    </script>

    <title>My page</title>

</head>

<body>
   <div class="historysearch">
      <input id="textinput" type="text" value="Search  "/>                              
   </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `val()` method to get the the input value not `.text`

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {

    alert('before...' + $(this).val());

    if ($(this).val() == "Search") {
      $(this).val("You have set me to value.");
      $(this).css({
        "style.color": "#000000"
      });
      $(this).css({
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).val("");
    }

    alert('after...' + $(this).val());

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="historysearch">
  <input id="textinput" type="text" value="Search  " />
</div>
```